# Z-ordering makes no difference for drag-and-drop operations in QtQuick 2.0

Tags: drag-and-drop, z-order, qtquick2

I've come across an interesting z-order problem in qt-quick 2.0. I've got an 8x8 grid of 64 items (a chessboard), and each square is a drag target. The pieces are created dynamically. I worked out how to drag and drop the pieces between squares; however, if a piece is created on square 9 (row 1, column 1), then when dragging it, it will appear /behind/ squares 10-63. Changing the value of "z" makes no difference. I've set "z" to 1000 on all pieces, and put "z: 0" in all other widget which can have a z value, and no difference.

// Found an Unprincipled Work-around //

It seems that there is no absolute z-ordering in qt-quick 2.0. (I find that hard to believe, but cannot find such.) Here is an hackish work around.

The z-order of the dragged piece is (seems?) relative to the square that the piece is in. So the piece drags correctly (i.e., is z-above the board) when the piece's square has the highest z-order. So I created a MouseArea on the square with Entered and Exited events that adjust the z-order before the drag operation starts:

```
DropArea
{
    id: square

    // ...

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors { fill: parent }
        color: isLightSquare() ? light_square_color : dark_square_color

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: square.z = 2
            onExited: square.z = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set absolute or relative positions on the z elements?

Comment: How do you set the absolute z-order? All I can find is the "z: ..." attribute. (?)